# How to run node js mongdb operation synchronously

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I have following code, I need to wait till mongodb operation completed.

```
const nativeClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

async function ingestData() {
  var data = [
    {name: "a", address: "a_add"},
    {name: "b", address: "b_add"}
  ];

  console.log(" start ingestData");
  await insertPersons(data);
  console.log("end ingestData");
}

async function insertPersons(data) {
  nativeClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", function(err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var db = client.db("testdb");

    db.collection("person")
      .insertMany(data)
      .then(function(res) {
        console.log(`Number of rec inserted:  ${res.insertedCount}`);
        return true;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(`Failed to persist ${data.length} rec in db:  ${err}`);
        return false;
      });
  });
}

ingestData();
```

**Current Output**

```
start ingestData
end ingestData
Number of rec inserted:  2
```

**Expected output**

```
start ingestData
Number of rec inserted:  2
end ingestData
```

Comment: As a general rule, you never want to turn an asynchronous process into a synchronous one. There always is a better way to handle the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `async`/`await` incorrectly.

- If you use `await`, the called function **must return a promise**, so there is something to wait for.
- If you are *not* using `await` anywhere in a function, that function does not need to be marked as `async`.

You're not doing either of these things.

You can return a promise that resolves when the work is done:

```
function insertPersons(data) {
  return nativeClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017").then(client => {
    return client.db("testdb").collection("person").insertMany(data).then(res => {
      console.log(`Number of rec inserted:  ${res.insertedCount}`);
      return true;
    });
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(`Failed to persist ${data.length} rec in db:  ${err}`);
    return false;
  });
}
```

or you can use `await` to wait until the work is done.

```
async function insertPersons(data) {
  try {
    let client = await nativeClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017"):
    let db = client.db("testdb");

    let res = await db.collection("person").insertMany(data);
    console.log(`Number of rec inserted:  ${res.insertedCount}`);

    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Failed to persist ${data.length} rec in db:  ${err}`);
    return false;
  }
}
```